# I am trying to build a simple calculator using java! Whats the error in my code?

Tags: java

I am new to java and wanted to build a simple calculator first but i don't know why my code is not working! Text field wont show the results whenever i press any button.
please guys help me out on dis!

Here's my ***Code*** :

```
       package com.example.calculator;

      import java.awt.Color;
      import java.awt.FlowLayout;
      import java.awt.GridLayout;
      import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
      import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

      import javax.swing.*;
      public class Gui implements ActionListener {
        double resu = 0;
        JTextField tf;
        JButton plusb,minusb,mulb,divb,resb;
        Gui(){
          JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Calculator");
          jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          jfrm.setVisible(true);
          jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          jfrm.setResizable(false);
          tf = new JTextField(18);
          plusb = new JButton("+");
          minusb = new JButton("-");
          mulb = new JButton("*");
          divb = new JButton("/");
          resb = new JButton("=");
          tf.addActionListener(this);

          plusb.addActionListener(this);
          minusb.addActionListener(this);
          mulb.addActionListener(this);
          divb.addActionListener(this);
          resb.addActionListener(this);

          jfrm.add(tf);
          jfrm.add(resb);
          jfrm.add(plusb);
          jfrm.add(minusb);
          jfrm.add(mulb);
          jfrm.add(divb);
          jfrm.setSize(275, 150);


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){


    switch((ae.getSource()).toString()){
    case "+" : resu = resu + Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
                        tf.setText("");
                        break;
    case "-" : resu = resu - Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");
    break;
    case "*" : resu = resu * Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");
    break;
    case "/" : resu = resu / Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");break;

    case "=" : tf.setText(String.valueOf(resu));
                resu=0;
    break;

    default : tf.setText("");
    break;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                    new Gui();
            }
        });
}
```

}

Comment: You shuold probably set the text to something else than an empty string (`tf.setText("");`)...

Comment: Only the `=` button seems to set the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 int resu = 0;
 switch (..) {
     case "+":
          resu = resu + Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
          break;
     ...
 }
 tf.setText("Result is " + resu);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you can't take the label of the button in this way, try this:

```
Object o = ae.getSource();
    JButton b = null;
    String s="";
    if(o instanceof JButton)
        b = (JButton)o;
    if(b != null)
        s = b.getText();
```

now you take in the right way the operator.
good luck whit java

Answer (score 0):

You can't not get source in your switch. This will return you the JButton.
Try to replace this:

```
switch((ae.getSource()).toString())
```

To:

```
switch(ae.getActionCommand())
```